# Unix shell: how to deal with filename with space while looping through the directory?

Tags: linux, unix, sh

Suppose in a directory there are two files

```
file1.jpg 
file 2.jpg
```

Here's my code to loop through the file:

```
for i in $dir/*
do 
   type=`exiftime -tg $i | cut -c-5`
done
```

The issue I have is when the loop looks at "file 2.jpg", it treats it as two files because of the space, "file" and "2.jpg".  How do I get it to treat the file as one file?

Comment: Always *Quote* your variables to prevent *word-splitting* (e.g. `"$i"`). Yes, quotes *are* permitted (and necessary) within *command substitution* (e.g. `$(....)` or the same with *backticks*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose `$i` in double quotes: `"$i"`

Comment: For background, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: Quote `$dir` too; `for i in "$dir"/*`.  You cannot quote the asterisk because that will inhibit wildcard expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have another question, when I run exiftime -tg | cut -c-10 on an invalid pictures, it returns the entire message instead of just the first ten characters. Why does the cut not work here?

Comment: @user116064: If you have another question, post another question.